# Unable to run Django in pipenv shell

Tags: django, pipenv

If I run:

```
$ pipenv install django
$ pipenv shell
(user-nKDraKU3) $ python manage.py shell
```

I get a ModuleNotFoundError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

...
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Shouldn't that work when I'm in the "activated" pipenv environment? However, this works fine:

```
$ pipenv run python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.5rc1 (default, Mar 14 2018, 06:54:23)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

Comment: Could you provide output of `which python` in your pipenv shell?

Comment: `/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/user-nKDraKU3/bin/python`

Comment: Is there a `django` directory in `/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/user-nKDraKU3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`?

Comment: Yes, the `django` package is there